# Closing class level LOGGER

Tags: java, logging

I am using "java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger" in class level, that are being used in two more methods in that particular class to write the on going things to a log file.

Now because of this ".lck" files are generated.

I got to know that if i close this logger using Handlers, this lock files will not be generated.

But as i have this in class level I cannot close this in each methods because it has to be accessed in the remaining methods.

How can i come over this?

Comment: Did you check the logging properties file? Like `logging.properties`? Is there some handlers specified?

Comment: I don't have a properties file for logging ! Is it mandatory? I have a config.properties file where i have stored the particular paths, but i don't have handlers specified in it.

Comment: you just need to close handlers before exiting your program, not required to close in each use

Comment: so i should make the logger as static? like "public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName());" ?
"